# CSS: vertical allign of a div not working

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to vertically align content of a div container; As it was my first time using this code i created a new file just to test it out, and it doesn't work at all. I've tried testing it in different browsers (Firefox,Opera and Chrome) and none of them worked as desired. As a reference i tried to use the folowing example to debug my code -http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

I would like to ask people with experience in it to help out.

Here is my code: 
HTML:

```
<div style="width: 50%; height: 10%; text-align: center; display: table cell; vertical-      align: middle; background-color: #87ceff; margin: 0px auto;min-height: 10%;">
some text
<p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: does the space between `vertical-      align:` is supposed to be there? or is it like `vertical-align:`?

Comment: Also, is `display: table cell` written like that in your code or is it a copy-paste mistake ?

Comment: Are you trying to vertically align both the text outside the `<p>` and inside the `<p>`?

Comment: [(Almost) verbatim jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22TvC/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some mistakes in your CSS:

- `display: table cell` should probably be `display: table-cell`
- `vertical-      align: middle` should probably be `vertical-align: middle`

Your HTML should define some outer container (table) that will contain the table cell:

```
<div id="center">
    <div>
        <div>some text
            <p>Some paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That inner `<div>` is required because table cells don't support `min-height`.

This is how your CSS would look like:

```
#center {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#center > div {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#center > div > div {
    min-height: 30%;
    background-color: #87ceff;
}
```

To demonstrate it, I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/54JNw/1/).

Comment: Thank you, now I finally get it. As for the incorrect syntax I apologize about that, i screwed it up while submitting the post (Identifying the code). Thank you very much and I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/thd4P/2/ it works.

```
<div style="width: 50%; height: 300px; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #87ceff; margin: 0px auto;min-height: 100px;">
    some text
    <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

What i did was to correct your syntax and set the height in `px` instead of percentual.

Comment: Thank you, now I finally get it. As for the incorrect syntax I apologize about that, i screwed it up while submitting the post (Identifying the code). Thank you very much and I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

> A FAQ on various IRC channels I help out on is How do I vertically center my stuff inside this area? This question is often followed by I'm using vertical-align:middle but it's not working!
>
> The problem here is three-fold:
>
> - HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width. Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing and layout was derived from that.
> - The reason vertical-align:middle isn't doing what is desired want is because the author doesn't understand what it's supposed to do, but …
> - … this is because the CSS specification really screwed this one up (in my opinion)—vertical-align is used to specify two completely different behaviors depending on where it is used.

[...]

> Method 1
>
> The following example makes two (non-trivial) assumptions. If you can meet these assumptions, then this method is for you:
>
> - You can put the content that you want to center inside a block and specify a fixed height for that inner content block.
> - It's alright to absolutely-position this content. (Usually fine, since the parent element inside which the content is centered can still be in flow.
>
> If you can accept the above necessities, the solution is:
>
> 1. Specify the parent container as position:relative or position:absolute.
> 2. Specify a fixed height on the child container.
> 3. Set position:absolute and top:50% on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
> 4. Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

[...]

> This method requires that you be able to satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - You have only a single line of text that you want to center.
> - You can specify a fixed-height for the parent element.
>
> If you can accept the above necessities, the solution is:
>
> 1. Set the line-height of the parent element to the fixed height you want.

[...]

So you can easily achieve what you desire by using `line-height=100%`, but that only works if you have a single line of text in the div and the div has a set size.

Comment: `line-height: 100%` is equivalent to `line-height: 1`, which (generally) makes the line shorter and doesn’t centre anything at all.